# Width resizing incorrectly in sticky menu (responsive)

Tags: html, css

so i have created this sticky menu

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5eb1q09n/)

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

I'm trying to make my site responsive, but when sticky menu get to the point where it stays fixed the width is changing. Just try out jsfiddle and you will understand. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: make that fiddle as link not the code

Comment: we can't get your fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

add `width:100%` to `#sticky.stick`

```
#sticky.stick {
  padding-top:5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  width:100%;
}
```

like this

http://jsfiddle.net/0e1mhs4u/

Comment: I tried this before aswell, but this does make another issue. The sticky menu width is now abit wider that it is on start.

Comment: this is the corrects answer. remove margin from the body and the spacing of the menu will stay consistent

Comment: try to set `width` to `97%` `98%` or remove margin from body

Comment: im sorry to say, but it does not work even if i remove margin from body. :S

Answer (score 0):

So, see here: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9wn5f3qw/)

```
#sticky.stick {
padding-top:5px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 10000;
width:100%;
}

#sticky.stick .boxes{
width:100%;
}

#sticky.stick .boxes .box{
width:33.3%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. Made it even worse in my Chrome :O

Answer (score 0):

just take the change the `max-width=100%` to `width=100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/5eb1q09n/1/

Answer (score 0):

make css like this

```
body {
margin:0;
}
#sticky {
max-width: 100%;
width:98%;
color: #fff;
}
#sticky.stick {
padding-top:5px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 10000;
left:0;
}

.boxes {
display:table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #858989;
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
}

.box {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height: 2em;
border-left: solid #858989 1px;
}

.box1 {
background: gray;
color: white;
}

.box2 {
background: white;
color: #858989;
}

.box3 {
background: white;
color: #858989;
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wL2qwqyc/